# EF Core - Unable to access navigation properties in Select()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to access the navigation Roles property of the IdentityUser model.

Inside GetQueryable function I am setting the include property

```
protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    string includeProperties = null
    )
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperties);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

If I execute following query, the roles property is populated successfully:

```
return GetQueryable<ApplicationUser>(e => e.Id == id, "Roles").SingleOrDefault();
```

But when I use the projection (Select) with following Dto:

```
public class ApplicationUserDto: BaseDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles{ get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserDto>> SelectProperties = (user) => new ApplicationUserDto {
        Id = user.Id,
        Email = user.Email,
        Name = user.Name,
        Roles = (List<IdentityUserRole<string>>)user.Roles
    };
}
```

Then the following query crashes:

```
return GetQueryable<ApplicationUser>(e => e.Id == id, "Roles").Select(ApplicationUserDto.SelectProperties).SingleOrDefault();
```

with the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type of navigation property 'Roles' on the entity type 'IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, IdentityUserRole
<string>, IdentityUserLogin<string>>' is 'ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>>' for which it was not possible to create a concrete instance. Either initialize the
property before use, add a public parameterless constructor to the type, or use a type which can be assigned a HashSet<> or List<>.
```

It also logs a warning:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryCompilationContextFactory[6]
      The Include operation for navigation: 'user.Roles' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.
```

Comment: I usually do Select(row => row.stuff). Where are you getting selectProperties from and why should that work in a Select

Comment: selectProperties is a property of Dto, if I remove the Roles property from Dto it works fine, but I don't get the roles

Comment: Isnt Roles an empty List <IdentityUserRole<string>>() in this case?

Comment: @EpicKip I even tried not initializing it, and only assigning it inside select() but still the same result

Comment: please show the full code for GetQueryable

Comment: please update your examples with the actual TEnitity's being used, its hard to follow what your doing otherwise

Comment: @Seabizkit updated

Comment: What happens if you put ```Roles = user.Roles.ToList() ?```

Comment: @adnankamili thanks!!!, now let me see if i can follow

Comment: @MarcinZablocki in ICollection Roles ToList() method doesn't exist

Comment: @adnankamili do you have ```using System.Linq;```?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Iwas missing System.Linq it worked when I used user.Roles.Select(role=> role.RoleId).ToList() ,  you can post this as an answer

Comment: I'm glad to hear that

Comment: Omfg that was pretty much the first thing I said but you just weren't using linq... I should'v known haha I feel stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in EF Core 1.1 `Include` is ignored if we use `Select()`, refer to following:

**Ignored includes section:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

That is the reason it was showing the warning:

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryCompilationContextFactory[6]
      The Include operation for navigation: 'user.Roles' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.
```

and `ToList()` also didn't work. So another projection was required on the navigation properties for it to work.

```
    public static Expression<Func<ApplicationRole, ApplicationRoleDto>> SelectProperties = (role) => new ApplicationRoleDto
    {
        Id = role.Id,
        Name = role.Name.Substring(0, role.Name.Length - role.TenantId.Length),
        Description = role.Description,
        // another projection on Claims navigation property
        Claims = role.Claims.Select(claim => claim.ClaimValue).ToList(),
    };
```

**Note:** Their is also a performance issue in this case, since eager loading doesn't occur if we use Select() on a list (since Include() is ignored) it will generate a separate sql query to fetch navigation property of each element in the result set.

On the other hand, if we **only** use `Include()`, it does a join as expected and hence performs better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to materialize (execute the subquery, which will gather Roles explicitly) in order to assign it to your DTO:

```
public class ApplicationUserDto: BaseDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles{ get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserDto>> SelectProperties = (user) => new ApplicationUserDto {
        Id = user.Id,
        Email = user.Email,
        Name = user.Name,
        Roles = user.Roles.ToList()
    };
}
```

And remember to add:

`using System.Linq;`

to your file in order to be able to call `.ToList()` on `ICollection`.

As you stated in comments, the type you want is a string, so you can do anything after the `user.Roles`, i.e perform further projection like this:

```
user.Roles.Select(role=> role.RoleId).ToList()
```

Just remember to materialize the results afterwards.

Comment: user.Roles.ToList() didn't work, it throws the same error, but I was interested in the properties so user.Roles.Select() worked for me. Thanks a lot.